# How to access and update weight of each layer using fit_generator in Keras?

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, optimization, keras, conv-neural-network

I want to experiment with the weights and biases of each layer during optimization. I am currently working on [Cats Vs Dogs dataset](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/eng-edu/blob/master/ml/pc/exercises/image_classification_part1.ipynb)
. Here, after compiling the model data is passed through ***model.fit_generator()***.

I want to get the weight and gradient of each layer while updating to apply a threshold (if gradient value is less than the threshold, weights won't get updated).

I tried to implement a custom ***fit_generator***, but i also want the ***fit_generator***'s parallelism for efficiency, real-time data augmentation on images on CPU in parallel to training the model on GPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a custom fit_generator method. Just a custom optimiser.
The optimiser defines the weight update operations. So you can define a custom optimiser that would implement a similar strategy to sgd or Adam after the weights are clipped.

The key is to define a class that descends from `keras.optimizers.Optimizer` and implements a `get_updates` method. This method determines how the grad weights are updated. In your version you can clip the gradients.

I can point you to some example code: I wrote a custom optimiser that allow one to use SciPy optimizers rather than sgd (https://github.com/pedro-r-marques/keras-opt). It is just a few lines of code so it should be reasonable to use as example.

Comment: When I try to run this line "model.compile(optimizer=GradientObserver(), loss='mse')" i get this error "Can't instantiate abstract class GradientObserver with abstract methods get_config" @pedromarques

Comment: @Leolime would you telling me what version of keras / TF you are using. It seems that newer versions of the API require that method to be defined.

Comment: Both keras master and tensorflow master seem to define ```get_config``` in the Optimizer base class. I've just rerun the unit tests on tensorflow 1.13 that seems to work just fine.

Comment: I'm using TF 1.14.0 @pedromarques

Comment: thanks a lot, @pedromarques, I've downgraded tensorflow to 1.13.1, now it's working :D

Comment: Why you didn't use steps_per_epoch in fit_generator() ? @pedromarques

Comment: @Leolime I have not had the need to use it so far. Feel free to open a GitHub issue or a pull request. AFAIK it should be a question of simply passing a parameter through the call stack.

Comment: I used your optimizer for cats and dogs dataset, but it took much time to train, after 2 hours it showed 5% progress, so i had to shut down training :( @pedromarques

Comment: @Leolime I wouldn't recommend it for any problem where you are injecting noise; for instance any model with a dropout layer. I use it to factorize sparse matrices where having batch based SGD doesn't seem to work as different batches push the solution into different directions.